# I want to ad a date of birth when enter information for an client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Hi im using ruby on rails, when i enter the date of birth on the years is just giving me from 2007 to 2012, 
i have this command on my db, i bold the one that is giving me the error, the thing is i need to have all the options to select a date of birth and also to select them in the future of course

```
class CreatePacientes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pacientes do |t|
      t.string :cedula
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :apellido1
      t.string :apellido2
      **t.date :fecha_nacimiento**
      t.string :genero
      t.string :estado_civil
      t.string :provincia
      t.string :canton
      t.string :distrito
      t.text :otras_senas
      t.string :telefono_casa
      t.string :telefono_celular
      t.string :correo_electronico
      t.string :nacionalidad
      t.integer :anos_estudio
      t.string :profesion
      t.string :ocupacion

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your problem is probably not with your table column, but rather with your view or the view helper you used. Can you paste how your form code looks like?

Comment: I try to but i cant post the code yet! sorry is telling me i have less than 8 of reputation so i will need to wait 8 hours -.-

Comment: I will try to post it in the comment

Comment: This is part of my _form.html.erb

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Fecha de nacimiento:" %>
    <%= f.date_select :fecha_nacimiento %>
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of the `date_select` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select), you will see that it accepts these two options:

```
:start_year - Set the start year for the year select. Default is Time.now.year - 5.

:end_year - Set the end year for the year select. Default is Time.now.year + 5.
```

What you're seeing are the default values. Although I'm not sure why your max is 2012, not 2017, because it should be +/- 5 years. Anyway, try to pass the limits to get the range you need. Or don't use `date_select` if you need to input any year.